# Device yaw on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, rotation, orientation, angle

I want my app to work on both iOS and Android devices.

I need it to act like a compass when device lies on table, but without magnetometer - relative yaw is enough for me. I don't care about cases when device isn't placed flat.

In iOS I store reference attitude first:

```
motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
[motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];
```

...

```
referenceAttitude = [specific->motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude retain];
```

And when I need relative yaw, I take it this way:

```
attitude = specific->motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude;
[attitude multiplyByInverseOfAttitude:specific->referenceAttitude];    
return attitude.yaw;
```

How to make this in Android? In NDK there is file named android/sensor.h, but I am only able to get ASensorEvent::vector.roll which is rather rotation speed than angle, from queue and then calculate yaw this way:

```
yaw = 0;
```

...

```
yaw += ASensorEvent::vector.roll * dt;
```

This works okay on low rotation speeds, but it is very unaccurate. How can I get relative attitude on Android?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this code sample perfectly fits your requirements (at least from the title)

> In this post we will show how to get the sensor informatión of the
>   device to do a simple compass application.

http://www.codingforandroid.com/2011/01/using-orientation-sensors-simple.html

Comment: It seems that code uses magnetometer for calculating attitude.